# Why is this ajax request failing?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is probably a simple problem but I don't understand why this is happening.  Here is the reduced code:

Ajax call :

```
mydata = {'action':'update','options':options};
        console.log(mydata);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'dt/scripts/stoplight.php',
            data: mydata
            }).success(function(data){
            if (data == 1) {
                alert("Options Updated");
            }else{
                alert(data);
            }
        })
```

My data looks like this:

```
action
    "update"
options
    Object { OMS-S="0", OMS-N="0", OHS="0"}
```

To clarify, this is a copy and paste from the browser console.  The object is a valid object and is being passed via get like so:

```
https://*pathtomysite*/dt/scripts/stoplight.php?action=update&options%5BOMS-S%5D=0&options%5BOMS-N%5D=0&options%5BOHS%5D=0
```

This request hangs indefinately.

```
https://*pathtomysite*/dt/scripts/stoplight.php?action=update&options%5BOMS-S%5D=0&options%5BOMS-N%5D=0&options%5BOHS%5D=1
```

To further clarify.  Options is being generated like this:

```
$("#stoplight_apply").click(function(){
                var radios = $("#stoplight_options").find("input:radio:checked");
                options = {};
                $.each(radios, function( key, value) {
                    options[value.name] = value.value;
                });
                set_stoplight_options(options);
            })
```

This one works fine.

If any of these options are set to anything other than 0 then the php script it is going to works great!  If all of them are 0 then it hangs and loads indefinitely.

I commented out all the PHP that could be causing problems so currently the script does this:

```
$action = $_GET['action']; //Get or update
print_r($_GET['action']);
print_r($_GET['options']);
```

Why is this happening?

### UPDATE:

I think I found the problem.  All I did was change the word 'options' to 'test' and the php to print_r($_GET['test']) and it works fine.  WTH?

Comment: Add a error handler to see the error `$.ajax({
    url: 'dt/scripts/stoplight.php',
    data: mydata
}).done(function (data) {
    if (data == 1) {
        alert("Options Updated");
    } else {
        alert(data);
    }
}).fail(function(xhr, status, error){
    alert('error:' + status + ':' + error + ':' + xhr.responseText)
})`

Comment: I don't think you need 'action' and 'options' in quotes

Comment: { OMS-S="0", OMS-N="0", OHS="0"} is not a valid json, should be like { OMS-S:"0", OMS-N:"0", OHS:"0"}, please cross check once

Comment: Question updated to clarify json object

Comment: @andrew you don't *need* action and options in quotes but it is still valid.  I do it because I read once it is good practice.

Comment: @ArunPJohny No error is ever returned.  It hangs indefinitely waiting for a response from the server.

Comment: Use your browser's developer console to check what's going on with the HTTP request and whether you're really sending (or receiving) anything.

Comment: @N.B. I did/am.  It has the correct params. I updated my question with the solution.  But I still would like an explanation.

Comment: OK, and if you did all that, what does the response of the page say? You can see headers, therefore you can see the method being used and how the data is being sent (POST/GET, what the indexes are etc.). You can read the URL and inspect what happens and if your data reached the URL or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try**

Use `$_POST` not `$_GET`

```
$action = $_POST['action'];
print_r($_POST['action']);
print_r($_POST['options']);
```

**Ajax :**

```
var mydata = {'action':'update','options':options};
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'dt/scripts/stoplight.php',
   data: mydata,
   success: function(data){
       if(data.length) {
         alert('done')
       }            
   }
});
```

- Please do one by one (PHP -> JS -> HTML)
- Ajax : post some data and get data like `console.log(data);` and see what you got.
- Then do statement : `if(data.length)` `if(data.sucess==='YeahDone')` (JSON) whatever.. (check by your PHP script if all success `echo 'YeahDone';` for example..
- So do something with HTML or alert or whatever

Comment: If I pass a 1 in any of those options then the php script print out the values just fine.  The values are getting sent with Get.

Comment: Same symptoms even when using $_POST.

Comment: @Bil1 Ok , now I think you have problem with your PHP :D

Comment: One would think... But those 3 lines of php is honestly all that is in there. I commented everything else out.  I think it has to do with the object creation after all... I'm going to update my answer with what I found.

Comment: @l2aelba Glad you found this funny :-P.  I don't know for the life of me why 'options' : options when using a get or post request to a php script hangs the request.  I ended up changing it to 'settings':options with appropriate changes in the php file and everything else the same and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 options

  Object { "OMS-S":"0", "OMS-N":"0", "OHS":"0"}
```

Now I see why quotes are a good practice :P

Comment: I updated my question to reflect how options is getting generated.